# Hard-coding credentials for git on TFS

Tags: git, tfs

Unfortunately, [TFS currently doesn't support public/private key authentication](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3801342-add-support-for-ssh-keys-as-alternate-authenticati).
So, the only option I have to avoid having to type in my credentials every time I work with git, is hard coding my HTTPS credentials in `.git/config`, as such:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://name:pass@host/project
```

I need to do this for every project. So in case my password changes, I have to reapply this change for every project as well.

Is there a better way to hardcode my credentials (I'm using Mac OS)?

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio, but only TFS.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm not working on a windows system.

Comment: See: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Comment: Jesse is pointing in the right direction: I have both Windows and Linux users accessing Git repos hosted in TFS. One gotcha is using an old Git version: make sure to run 1.9.x or later.